# Importing editor toolbar in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, coordinates, editing

Is it possible to import editor toolbar in ModelBuilder of ArcGIS?

Basically I want to get coordinates of points on a shapefile (line) by randomly selecting, say 10 vertices and then using sketch feature in editor toolbar to know their coordinates. I want to automate this process.

Until now I have seen ModelBuilder is used only for geoprocessing tools and not for editor toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think this is possible in ModelBuilder.

But you could create a model that :

1. convert the line vertex to point
2. add XY (and if needed ZM) coordinate to the newly created point
3. select some of the point
4. Export a table with the coordinate you're after